# Magento 2: How to add websites dropdown in admin form?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

**Magento 2: Code to add "website" dropdown in admin form**

Answer (score 3):

You can use below code for add website drop down to admin form

```
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store
     */
    protected $_systemStore;


 public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore,
    ) {
        $this->_systemStore = $systemStore;
     }
```

> In function _prepareForm() add column

```
$fieldset->addField(
                'website_id',
                'select',
                [
                    'name' => 'website_id',
                    'label' => __('Associate to Website'),
                    'title' => __('Associate to Website'),
                    'required' => true,
                    'values' => $this->_systemStore->getWebsiteValuesForForm(),

            ]
        );
```

Comment: how i can get website label instead of website id. please help..

Comment: Already it's showing website label.

Comment: No its showing Id in database and grid also, in form only its showing label.

Comment: Yes it is save website id in database but it will show label on form and grid.

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/odqKiiuUvw

Comment: Please see this screencast

Comment: Yes I have checked but there is issue with grid collection column. show your grid column code which you have used.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80313/discussion-between-afreen-and-suresh-chikani).

Answer (score 0):

Add following code to your Form in file

**File:** Module\Custom\Block\Adminhtml\Custom\Edit\Form\Main.php

Code:

```
 /**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteFactory
 */
 protected $_websiteFactory;

 public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore,
    \Magewares\MWSlider\Model\Status $status,
    \Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteFactory $websiteFactory,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_systemStore = $systemStore;
    $this->_status = $status;
    $this->_websiteFactory = $websiteFactory;
    parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
}
```

In function **_prepareForm()** add column

```
 $websites = $this->_websiteFactory->create()->getCollection()->toOptionArray();
    $fieldset->addField(
        'website_id',
        'select',
        [
            'name' => 'website_id',
            'label' => __('Website'),
            'value' => $model->getWebsiteId(),
            'values' => $websites,
            'required' => true,
            'disabled' => false
        ]
    );
```